# What are worthless things I can give to the hermit?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

I need a Jabañero pepper, and the Hermit has one! Problem is, I don't have anything worthless to trade.

What items will the Hermit take in order for me to get my hands on that pepper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As discussed on kolwiki](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/The_Hermitage), the Hermit has an appetite for worthless items. This is not a metaphor, he actually wants [worthless trinkets](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Worthless_trinket), [worthless gee-gaws](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Worthless_gewgaw), and [worthless knick-knacks](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Worthless_knick-knack).

To find these worthless items, buy [chewing gum on a string](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Chewing_gum_on_a_string) from the general store and use it to fish junk items from a sewer grate. Some of these junk items are class starter items and thus "worthless" (but not in the way the Hermit will accept); hang on to this junk too!

The way the chewing gum on a string works is that it fishes up a random junk item **that you don't have in your inventory yet**, so selling the junk means that future chewing gums will get you more junk. The savvy adventurer will instead place their "worthless" (but still useful to the Hermit) items in their closet while they use chewing gum for more. After you hold all the junk items, you will **only get more worthless items**.

After you've used all your chewing gums, take the worthless items out of the closet and go visit the Hermit. And don't forget to buy your [hermit permit](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Hermit_permit) from the general store!